# Is there any ways to trigger session based on output of a command task in informatica powercenter?

Tags: shell, unix, session, informatica, informatica-powercenter

We have a command task in informatica workflow which returns result as two scenarios (A and B) as result.
If the result of command task is A then a session task should be triggered, if the result is B then no need of triggering the session.  Is there any scenarios to achieve this requirement?
Note: pls suggest without using pmcmd command

Answer (score 0):

You can do this easily using a new target like below.

1. Create a new mapping which will load result of scenario A only.  Name the target as Target_A. Create a session with this mapping.
2. In informatica workflow, right after above mapping, put your second session - which you want to execute when scenario A executed. In the link condition pls mention this
   `$PMTargetTarget_A@numAffectedRows>0`. The workflow will look like this -

```
-->CMD Task --> Session to Load for scenario A --$PMTargetTarget_A@numAffectedRows>0 --> session you want to run
```

You can use event raise as well but it would be similar to above solution.
You can use event wait too - like command for scenario will generate a file and a workflow will wait for that file and kick off the session if found.